# Understand which IP accesses more my server via terminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing, ip

I occasionally use this line in my terminal to see which user-agent is using my server more.

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk -F\" '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Scans the access.log and show in ascending order the user-agents that it has found several times.

The result is something like this:

```
  10283 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1
  23247 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
  40063 MauiBot (crawler.feedback+dc@gmail.com)
 143724 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
 192741 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)
```

I have no idea how it works, so long ago I found it somewhere or someone gave me the date, I do not remember.

Anyway, is possible do the same thing but ordering for IP?

Comment: Where did you find the command-line you are using? Could you post a link? BTW, there is a [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Comment: I don't remember... use it from a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I think IP is the on the first column in the log, try

```
awk '{print $1}' /var/log/apache2/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: Umh.. no, a lot of time the same ip...

Comment: It should give you a list of ip with a count in front of it. make sure the access log has not just rotated, if so you will need to parse older log files.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the fact that you're using `awk -F \" { print $6}` there, this appears like [combined log format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234855/3701431), which should have the IP address in field `$1`. From there, we can just do [uniq in awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193331/85039), then combine that with [sorting indices in associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2458455/3701431).

With a mock `access.log` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2012:17:11:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 140 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.5 Safari/535.19"
192.168.0.2 - - [05/Feb/2012:17:11:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 140 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.5 Safari/535.19"
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2012:17:11:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 140 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.5 Safari/535.19"
```

the `awk`  code should be as so:

```
$ awk '{!a[$1]++}; END{n=asorti(a,sorted);for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print sorted[i],":",a[sorted[i]]}' access.log
127.0.0.1 : 2
192.168.0.2 : 1
```

For numeric sorting by the number of entries for each ip address, we can just stick `sort` at the end:

```
$ awk '{!a[$1]++}; END{for(val in a) print val,":",a[val];}' access.log | sort -n --field-separator=":" -k 2,2
```

Of course, you should use `/var/log/apache2/access.log` as your actual input file.

Comment: This seems to work, but only shows IP and how many times it has entered, I would also like to know who is, maybe from the user-agent, is it possible?

Comment: @alebal Know who is ? As in making a querry via `whois` command ? You might want to ask a separate question maybe

Comment: I would like to use it for example to identify and block the bad bots, if there was also the user agent would be much more comfortable, is not possible?